# Tell ConfigurationManager to ignore App.config section

Tags: c#, app-config

My App.config file is markuped as:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="Custom" type="…" />
    </configSections>
    <Custom>
        ...
    </Custom>
    <Ignored>
        ...
    </Ignored>
</configuration>
```

So, I have an configuration file, where:

- one section ("Custom") is handled by API and I have written ConfigurationSection inheritor for it
- second section ("Ignored") I will parse by myself, because Configuration API doesnt let me solve my task.

When I run program, exception occurs "Unrecognized configuration section 'Ignored'".

Do I have possibility to tell ConfigurationManager to ignore this section "Ignored"?

Comment: write it in another xml file

Comment: I dont think you can ConfigManager to ignore it. Other alternative is to use a xml or resource file to carry the information

Comment: Write config block in another xml file - it's obvious decision, but I don't want to produce plenty of configuration types. I want to define just one unified configuration in App.config but with different kinds of internal readers - default ConfigurationManager for known sections and my custom manager for mine sections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the following to your `<configSections>` element:

```
<section name="Ignored" type="System.Configuration.IgnoreSection, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

Comment: Thanks! I found that exact solution one-two days after posting question.